# multiprocessing_on_dill results in ModuleNotFoundError "__builtin__"

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dill

To overcome the limitations of pickle, I switched to `multiprocessing_on_dill`.

This started to generate an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 117, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

Is there a way to overcome it?

Surprisingly, it still references `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\`. 
While `multiprocessing_on_dill` has its own folder `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\multiprocessing_on_dill` with the same set of files.

Comment: I'd suggest that you post a simple self-contained example that produces your error. That way others can run your code, see the error, and help you diagnose it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use `multiprocess` instead of `multiprocessing_on_dill`... the former is better supported, and maintained by the `dill` author (me).  It looks like `multiprocess_on_dill` is looking for `__builtin__`, which is where the builtin functions lived in python 2... in python 3, they are in `builtins`

```
>$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  1 2019, 14:50:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import __builtin__
>>> 

>$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Dec 30 2018, 13:04:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import __builtin__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
>>> import builtins
>>>
```

So, I think it's either you are running python 3, and using the python 2 version of the code -- or the module doesn't fully support python 3.